# Can't Decode With JSONDecoder

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

How can I decode this JSON by using JSONDecoder? I'm trying, but I always ended up crashing. I have another post talking about it but the error was bigger before, now I'm stucked only on that. I also tried by using JSONSerialization, but I think using JSONDecoder is more clean.

I got this error message when the compiler pass by JSONDecoder part:

> Could not get API data. typeMismatch(Swift.Array, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)), The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

This is how I'm trying to parse all my data:

```
import Foundation

//typealias AudiobookJSON = [[String: Any]]

struct APIClient {

    static func getAudiobooksAPI(completion: @escaping ([Audiobook]?) -> Void) {

        let url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/categoria")

        let session = URLSession.shared

        guard let unwrappedURL = url else { print("Error unwrapping URL"); return }

        let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: unwrappedURL) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let unwrappedDAta = data else { print("Error unwrapping data"); return }

            do {


                let posts = try JSONDecoder().decode([Audiobook].self, from: unwrappedDAta)

                print(posts)


                completion(nil)

            } catch {
                print("Could not get API data. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
    }
}
```

***Struct that I'm using:***

```
import Foundation

struct Data : Decodable {

    let data : [Audiobook]
}

struct Audiobook: Decodable {
    let id : Int?
    let descricao : String?
    let urlImagem : String?

//    init(dictionary: Audiobook) {
//        self.descricao = dictionary["descricao"] as! String
//        self.urlImagem = dictionary["urlImagem"] as! String
//
//    }
}
```

***JSON to be parsed:***

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "descricao": "Games",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/39ahd9aq5l9101brf3b8dq58.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2013\/06\/3D-Gaming.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "descricao": "Livros",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/4.bp.blogspot.com\/-6Bta1H9d22g\/UJAIJbqcHhI\/AAAAAAAAKi4\/hvgjWrlFc64\/s1600\/resenha-missiologia.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "descricao": "Celulares",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/pt.seaicons.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2015\/11\/Mobile-Smartphone-icon.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "descricao": "Inform\u00e1tica",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/portal.ifrn.edu.br\/campus\/ceara-mirim\/noticias\/ifrn-oferece-curso-de-informatica-basica-para-pais-dos-estudantes\/image_preview"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "descricao": "Eletrodom\u00e9stico",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/classificados.folharegiao.com.br\/files\/classificados_categoria\/photo\/8\/sm_4d5ed3beb0f31b61cb9a01e46ecd0cf9.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "descricao": "TVs",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/i.utdstc.com\/icons\/256\/terrarium-tv-android.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "descricao": "Filmes e S\u00e9ries",
      "urlImagem": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/801033586438733824\/91Y_N91t_reasonably_small.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 8,
      "descricao": "M\u00f3veis e Decora\u00e7\u00f5es",
      "urlImagem": "https:\/\/image.flaticon.com\/icons\/png\/128\/148\/148188.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 9,
      "descricao": "Moda, Beleza e Perfumaria",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/icon-icons.com\/icons2\/196\/PNG\/128\/fashion_23852.png"
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "descricao": "Papelaria",
      "urlImagem": "http:\/\/esen.pt\/in\/images\/stories\/skills_256.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting where?  Or what makes you think it's not working?

Comment: Hello @DavidBerry! Well, when I debug the code the compiler just go straight to catch statement skiping the JSONDecoder part

Comment: If you just let it run from there, does it print any messages?

Comment: And are you running it in a program, or in the playground?

Comment: @DavidBerry  I'm running it as a normal project on XCode. I just updated the post with the Error Message could you check, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to decode it as `[AudioBook]` when the data is actually a dictionary wrapping the array, as in your `Data` structure.  Just change it to:

```
let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Data.self, from: unwrappedDAta)
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ohh! Might be that. Let me test, give me one minute

Comment: You're correct! Completely my bad, but now how can I say something like: data.id and description and etc? Because I still not able to do that

Comment: `data?.data[0]` would be the first actual record.  I'd suggest some name changes to be more consistent and legible :)  Change the `data` item in the `Data` structure to something more indicative of it's usage, like `books`.   You can currently use `completion(data.data)` to pass the list of books to your completion routine.

Comment: I'll adopt you suggestions about changing names =). What if I create an init to be able to access straight like: print(data.description! or data.id!)? Looks simple than access the position [0] then proceed... What do you think?

Comment: One more question. On my function completion I still returning the following data, is that correct? getAudiobooksAPI(completion: @escaping ([Audiobook]?) -> Void) {

Comment: If you want to access all of the books you really don't have a choice about leaving that level in.

Comment: That's any "elegant" way to do parsing instead of what I'm doing? If so, please let me know I want to learn the best way possible (Ios Dev Senior way =) )

Comment: `JSONDecoder` is the preferred option for JSON parsing, even more so for structured data like this.

Comment: Gotcha. So, let me ask one more question just to clarify? What if I want to populate a tableview using the data I just parsed? Let's say I want populate with Description. What would be my next step now?

Comment: But I mean, I gotta call my function every time or I could just instance my Struct to access the properties?

Comment: You’ll call it once and save the array.  A good tutorial will explain it.

Comment: Because the JSONDecoder which gives me all the data belongs to the function. What about using the data in other Files on my project?

Comment: Oh, ok! Gotcha. Would you recommend me some?